# Assign shortcut to item in WPF ComboBox

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to assign the shortcut to every item in combobox control. Also I want the shortcut "letter" is underlined (for label/textbox pair I would use the _ symbol to achieve the desired effect).

For example, there is a combobox containing names: Alex, John, Sandra. I want press lets say Alt+e for selecting Alex, Alt+o for selecting John and Alt+a for Sandra. Is it doable without creating my own control?

Answer (score 1):

This is the ListBox version.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button Click="btnAlpha_Click">
                <AccessText>_alpha</AccessText>
            </Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button Click="btnBravo_Click">
                <AccessText>_beta</AccessText>
            </Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button Click="btnCharlie_Click">
                <AccessText>_charlie</AccessText>
            </Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I'll consider using ListBox to achieve the desired behavior. But it seems that I can't use combobox for this and that's a pain.

Comment: With enough tweaking I suspect it will work in ComboBox.  When I tried moving this simple code directly over to ComboBox it did not work.  But at least is shows you how <AccessText> works.  The quick key only comes when alt is depressed.